# AMP list with pagination and dynamic [src]

Tags: html, json, amp-html

I'm trying to implement AMP List with page pagination and data fetched from REST API JSON.

Here is my `amp-html`:

```
<button on="tap:AMP.setState({ srcUrl: '/wp-json/posts/v2/category/', pageNumber: '1', pageCat: 'updates' })">UPDATES</button>
<button on="tap:AMP.setState({ srcUrl: '/wp-json/posts/v2/category/', pageNumber: '1', pageCat: 'events' })">EVENTS</button>
    
<amp-list class="paged-amp-list" layout="fixed-height" height="450" src="/wp-json/posts/v2/category/events/1" data-amp-bind-src="'/wp-json/posts/v2/category/' + pageCat + '/' + pageNumber" binding="no" single-item reset-on-refresh>
    <template type="amp-mustache">
        <p class="info">Page {{currentPage}} of {{pageCount}}</p>
        <div class="items">
            {{#posts}}
                <div>
                    <strong class="title">{{title}}</strong>
                    <p>{{excerpt}}</p>
                    <div><a href="{{link}}" title="{{title}}">READ MORE</a></div>
                </div>
            {{/posts}}
        </div>
    </template>
</amp-list>
<div class="navigation">
    <button class="prev" data-amp-bind-hidden="pageNumber < 2" on="tap: AMP.setState({ pageNumber: pageNumber - 1 })" i-amphtml-binding="" hidden="">Previous</button>
    <button class="next" data-amp-bind-hidden="page ? pageNumber >= page.items.pageCount : false" on="tap: AMP.setState({ pageNumber: pageNumber ? pageNumber + 1 : 2 })" i-amphtml-binding="">Next</button>
</div>
<amp-state id="page" src="/wp-json/posts/v2/category/events/1" data-amp-bind-src="'/wp-json/posts/v2/category/' + pageCat + '/' + pageNumber"></amp-state>
```

Here is my JSON: `/wp-json/posts/v2/category/events/1`, where `events` is name of category and last number is page number:

```
{
   "items":{
      "currentPage":"1",
      "pageCount":2,
      "posts":[
         {
            "title":"Stay up-to-date with the one latest tech trends [cloned]",
            "excerpt":"Readymade godard brooklyn, kogi shoreditch hashtag hella shaman kitsch man bun pinterest flexitarian. Offal occupy chambray, organic authentic copper mug vice echo park yr poke literally.",
            "link":"https:\/\/staging.dev\/stay-up-to-date-with-the-one-latest-tech-trends-cloned-2\/"
         },
         {
            "title":"Stay up-to-date with the one latest tech trends [cloned]",
            "excerpt":"Readymade godard brooklyn, kogi shoreditch hashtag hella shaman kitsch man bun pinterest flexitarian. Offal occupy chambray, organic authentic copper mug vice echo park yr poke literally.",
            "link":"https:\/\/staging.dev\/stay-up-to-date-with-the-one-latest-tech-trends-cloned\/"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Output on page load:
[image]

On load and category buttons clicks all works fine.

Buttons are setting states for `pageCat` and `pageNumber`.

On load default category in `src` is `events` and `pageNumber` is 1.

The problem is that after changing page by clicking `next` button, category in `src` setted to null:

/wp-json/posts/v2/category/`null`/2

**How I can avoid changing `pageCat` to null?**